# Bring Activity Indicator to the top

Tags: ios, ios7

I have a UIActivityIndicator which is added to the self of the view as shown below:

```
self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[self.spinner setColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
self.spinner.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:self.spinner];
```

The issue is that when I dynamically add UINavigationController with a view in it as shown below, my spinner goes behind so its not visible once nav controller is created. If I add activity indicator to the nav controller which will work for the first time but when I do paging as the nav controller is dynamically created, on each paging calls it will not work for the following requests as it will be overwritten by nav controller.

```
self.navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.detailViewController
```

What I am trying to achieve is to show activity indicator between service calls or bring it to the top of the stack when the service  call is being made so its not behind the nav conroller and the view sitting on nav controller. Is it possible to bring the activity indicator to the top of stack for service calls?

Comment: Try to add spinner on the appdelegate.window..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to move your spinner to the front, you can do it like this:

`[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.spinner];`

I'm not exactly clear on how your navigation controller fits in the view hierarchy, but you could potentially use a `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to make sure bringSubviewToFront is called at appropriate times.